# IdentityCore Login or Register doesn't redirect back to home/index

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

i'm having problem with IdentityCore.
When i press the login button on the login form i do not get redirected to the index view, same with the register button.

This is how debug goes

1. I fill in the form correctly
2. I press the login button
3. The Login Action is called
4. Modelstate is valid and result succeeded
5. "User logged in" gets logged
6. RedirectToLocal(null) gets returned
7. Dependency injection calls
8. The Index action in home controller is called
9. Dishes gets loaded correctly
10. it returns View(dishes)
11. it stays in the login view instead of going to home/index

Login Form:

```
       <form asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
            <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                        <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>
                    <a asp-action="ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]">Register as a new user?</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Login Action:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var dishes = _context.Dishes
           .Include(d => d.IngredientDish)
           .ThenInclude(id => id.Ingredient)
           .Include(d => d.Category)
           .ToList();

        return View(dishes);
    }
}
```

If you need more codesnippets or information do let me know

Comment: If you just navigate to Index/Home does it do the same thing or is this only after you login?

Comment: Only after login

Comment: Is the browser reloading the login view or staying on the same page?

Comment: It's staying on the same page as if the button did nothing

Comment: Are you attempting to use ajax to login?

Comment: No, standard Mvc

Comment: Seems that authentication isn't send along with the request. If you are using cookies, check your code where you configure the cookie. If you are using bearer token, add the token to your request.